# How does DB engine traverse down the clustered and non-clustered tables?

Tags: sql-server, tree, tree-traversal

I'm trying to understand how SQL Server 2014 works while it's trying to find records in a table with clustered index or in a table with non-clustered indexes.

There are two great figures in the following pages demonstrating the tree structure:

[Clustered Index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174523(v=sql.80).aspx)

[Non-clustered Index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174537(v=sql.80).aspx)

What I don't know is how the DB engine goes down from the top of the tree in both cases. Starting from I just know that I could traverse a binary tree with recursive left traversal but I'm not sure in this one.

For example, in the clustered case, to access a row(s) in the page F, what other nodes the DB engine needs to visit?

[image: Clustered table]

Comment: There is no difference in operations on CI and NCI indexes. The distinction is quite artificial in my mind.

Comment: Every pointer to a page shows the first and last version on that page. A clustered index is physically sorted in that order, more or less like a phonebook. If you're looking for someone with last name Jablowski, the root would show something like Page C starting with IO and Finishing with JO. Page C then has pointers to page E, F, and G, where it shows F would contain data starting with JAA and ending with JAC.

Comment: @SchmitzIT Clustered index tables are **logically** in order, not physically. Inserting a record in the middle of the key range is not going to cause SQL Server to copy half the table to make room. This is the nature of tree indexes.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - Interesting. That is counter to how I understand it works. Do you have something I could read up on? Tried some googling, but I only keep reading a clustered index does physically sort the data

Comment: @SchmitzIT Nothing handy. A table with a clusted index is holding the table contents along with the keys in the leaf nodes. Where as a normal index holds the key and pointers to the row in the leafs. So to learn about how clusted index tables are stored, learn about indexes. || Consider OP's diagram, all all the entries on leaf page F are logically prior to the entries on leaf page G, just as F is logically prior to G. But maybe F was created when E got too full, and was inserted between E & G. F will come from a free block, SQL Server is not going to copy G+ pages to make room.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance But that's where the fill factor comes in. Of course it won't simply bump everything up when a new insert comes in.

Comment: @SchmitzIT, I'm talking about when the page is full. No fill factor setting is available to allow infinite additions to a page. With split of a full page, a free page will be used and logically inserted, there will **not** be a move of other data to make room. No sane database is going to take a tree based index with O(log n) insert and turn it into a structure with O(n) insert to maintain a physical sort order.